# Algorithm for fitting a string inside rectangle bounds

Tags: c#, algorithm, math

I am trying to write an algorithm for fitting a string inside a rectangle, the catch is that each letter is an another rectangle, an image of the actual letter with modifiable dimensions.
My current algorithm simply reduces width and height of each letter's rectangle until the total width (sum of all letters' width) is less than the width of the main rectangle. This works fine on fitting the string in a single line but line wrapping is my problem.

Any suggestions or references on this subject would be helpful.

I am working in .net C# environment.

Thanks.

Edit:
1) This is a sample of the desired result (it can fit into more than 2 lines)
[image: Sample of desired result]

2) the final result will be rendered on an image using a custom built rendering algorithm.

3) current fitting algorithm:

```
do
{
    ratio -= 0.05f;
    FinalHeight = (int)(height * ratio);
    totalWidth = GetTotalWidth(FinalHeight, text);
 } 
 while (totalWidth > DestRectangle.Width);

int GetTotalWidth(int Height, char[] Text)
{
    int totalWidth = 0;
    int spaces = 0;
    float letterHeight = 0;

    foreach (char c in Text)
    {
        if (Char.IsWhiteSpace(c))
        {
            spaces++;
            continue;
         }

         BoundingRect bounds = GetBoundingRectangle(c);

         float letterWidth = bounds.Width;
         letterHeight = bounds.Height;
         int width = (int)((letterWidth * Height) / letterHeight);
         totalWidth += width;
    }

    totalWidth += (int)(spaces * (totalWidth / Text.Length));

    return totalWidth;
}
```

Comment: If possible, please post some images of the desired result.

Comment: Please also state what UI language you are using. Winforms, WPF, or ASP.NET? The way to measure string size is different for each of those platforms. Also [editing your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34664729/edit) to include your current algorithm will greatly help people who are trying to provide answers.

Comment: *This works fine on fitting the string in a single line but line wrapping is my problem.* How so? You want to automatically line wrap? Under what circumstances?

Comment: @MattBurland Forgot to mention that if the height of one line is less than 2/3 of the destination rectangle line wrap should occur. this applies recursively on each line break

Comment: Could you elaborate what `Class` or library you're using to render the text? Honestly think you might be reinventing the wheel here.

Comment: SGM1 is right - Windows already knows how to do this for you - but we need to know your environment in order to guide you to the correct classes/functions to use.

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms? WPF? ASP? ...?? __Always__ tag your question accordingly! - In winforms the DrawString overload with a Rectangle will already do the wrapping for you.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem to be a trivial problem.

I would try this line of attack: given the placement of the white spaces, you can enumerate all possible phrase fragments (such as "This", "This is", "This is a" ... "random", "random text", ...). For N words, there are N.(N+1)/2 possibilities.

For every fragment, compute its actual width. Then determine the word wrapping such that this width will not be exceeded on the other rows. This tells you the number of required rows. (For some fragments, this will be impossible.)

For example, the fragment "a random" should yield

```
This is
a random
text to
fit
```

and "random text"

```
This is a
random text
to fit
```

Now you have a bounding box and you can tell what scaling factor will fit it in the given rectangle (filling either vertically or horizontally).

In the end, keep the largest scaling.

Comment: I honest doubt he isn't using a library that already tells him the bound box.

Comment: I'm saying he probably does, if he using a standard library. I only remember doing something hacky like this for a small game in Java when I was too lazy in finding a decent library. I can't `@` include u Yves. Anyway, even then, Java `Rectangle` weren't hard to do bounds checking.

Comment: @SGM1: this is a chicken and egg problem as the word wrapping depends on the character size and the character size depends on the word wrapping. The OP is currently addressing this by a kind of trial and error process.